# 3rd-Party Software for updating my end-user's application

Tags: software-development, automation, file-synchronization, ftp

So, We are a small development firm that works developing custom softwares for industrial sites. Normally, we don't need to send patches to our clients and, when needed, it's done in front of the customer computer, locally.

Currently, we're working with 'normal products'. Now, I need some kind of updating system to apply patches in client's machine. I'm looking for a simple system, no version-control, just something like a client-side redistributable to embed in our product installation - and then check for updates in a website directory or whatever.

I don't know even how to google it. I've found some software to update clients inside the corporation (not end-user) and some source-codes like google update.

We can handle the server-side, inserting the exe files in correct location and etc. The real need here is to update the software in our client's machine automatically.

Samples:
Atlassian Source Tree Update software,
Google, Firefox, Opera, Steam, Spotify updater,
Any another software that auto-updates itself.

Is there some redistributable like this? Or may I develop this simple client-side by myself? Framework, Library, maybe?

EDIT: Just found ATL SourceTree uses Advanced Installer. Something similar to?

(And sorry, it's my first question in stack networrk. Didn't find any recommendations yet)

Comment: If you don't find it (and I hope that you do), you will have to implement it. Encode a version number in your executable. At start-up, encode that into an HTTP GET request `http://your_company.com/version_check.php?current_version=<X>`, which returns a response telling you whether you need to update, or not. If so, another HTPP request to D/L the new app, then install it.  When coding Delphi, or C++ Builder, I use https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/wupdate.asp It might give you a few ideas

Comment: I guess we decided to develop ourself this implementation, at least for now. Since we can only 'replace' the exe files in most of cases, we're going to develop a simple app to read the latest version in our server in the same way we already upload to the web and download the new .exe if needed. It's probably not the best and most automated way, but will solve the problem. Saved 'TWebUpdate' for later use. Thanks!